# I cannot access the inner field of a defrecord object. All standard approaches keep returning nil

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, lisp

Essentially I have a "Cell" object named `sample-cell` that looks like this when output `[#grid_generator.core.Cell{:coordinates [1.0 1.0], :value 3.0}]`.  I'm simply trying to access the `:coordinates` field within it.  Whenever I try `(:coordinates sample-cell)` though, I simply get `nil`.

I can't for the life of me figure out why my code isn't working.  I have also tried `get-in` with the same results (just in case there is a nesting issue) and I still get the same issue.  This is my first project so I expect some hangups.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: welcome in - share a minimal example of your code, I'm sure one of the many experts here will spot the issue right away. From what you shared it looks like maybe you need `(::coordinates sample-cell)`, but there isn't enough context to say for sure.

Answer (score 3):

From the printout, it looks like you have put your cell in a vector with that cell being the single element:

```clj
(defrecord Cell [coordinates value])

(def sample-cell [(Cell. [1.0 1.0] 3)])

sample-cell
;; => [#grid_generator.core.Cell{:coordinates [1.0 1.0], :value 3}]
```

Just asking to lookup the key `:coordinates` in that vector is not going to work:

```clj
(:coordinates sample-cell)
;; => nil
```

What will work, however, is first asking for the `first` element in that vector and then get the `:coordinates`:

```clj
(:coordinates (first sample-cell))
;; => [1.0 1.0]
```

... or you can simply address the presumed root issue and make sure that `sample-cell` is exactly an instance of `Cell`:

```clj
(def sample-cell (Cell. [1.0 1.0] 3))

(instance? Cell sample-cell)
;; => true
```